# docker API delete container not working

Tags: docker

I access the docker API via Angular/Javascript and I can issue GET and POST calls, but when trying to remove a container with DELETE, I get "404 Not Found".

I use: `http://192.168.50.6:2375/containers/8436f95d8b0d?v=1`
I changed /etc/default/docker:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://192.168.50.6:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -r=true --api-cors-header=http://localhost:8880"
```

When I use Chrome without security ("google-chrome --disable-web-security") the call works.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably given the wrong value to the `--api-cors-header` parameter. Try `--api-cors-header=*` and see if that fixes it. If it does, you should replace `*` with the host the Javascript is being served from.

Comment: Yes, I know the star option, it works, but I do not want to allow any host.

Comment: As I said in my question, GET and POST requests work as expected with the given --api-cors-header setting, so why should I have to change it for a DELETE??

Comment: Because if you read the CORS spec, most GET and POST requests (unless they have certain headers) can bypass CORS preflight checks.